# knockout: ko observable without a default value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am just learning knockout, came across the tutorials to work with lists.

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
        var price = self.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
    });
}
```

In the tutorial, this code defines an observable meal, that will be the choice selected in a dropdown select. In case if I do not have a default value, say for example I want to use a radio group instead of select. I want to be able to create an observable without any default value. I tried with an empty string as default value, then it works

```
self.meal = ko.observable("");
```

whereas if I try null as a default value, the select options does not even appear.

```
self.meal = ko.observable(null); // not working
```

what is the right way to create an observable without default value?

Comment: if the empty string does what you need, then it's the right way to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can intialize your observable to `null` with

```
 self.meal = ko.observable(null);
```

Or to `undefined` with

```
 self.meal = ko.observable();
```

However in this case you have to handle the case when the `meal` if in fact `null` or `undefined` because when you write something like **`self.meal().price;` it will throw an exception because you try to access a property of "nothing"**.

So you need to fix the `formattedPrice` computed:

```
self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!self.meal())
        return "None";
    var price = self.meal().price;
    return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";        
});
```

And the `totalSurcharge` computed to check for the `self.meal()` case:

```
self.totalSurcharge = ko.computed(function() {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < self.seats().length; i++)
   {
       if (self.seats()[i].meal())
       total += self.seats()[i].meal().price;
   }
   return total;
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdw2otc5/).

Note: it is working with the empty string by accident (because the empty string is an object so it is valid to access properties on them like `self.meal().price` however all of these will return undefined) so it is not a proper solution.

Comment: "".price is undefined which is false, which in the OP's code triggers the "None" string.

Comment: @nemesv you are awesome. Just what i was looking for.